# How can I find out which JS file is rerouting URLs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-devtools

I have a large project written in AngularJS and other framweworks.

When a URL is entered into the browser, it is somehow parsed and turned into something else that generates the path to the view that is to be displayed.

Trouble is, I don't know what mechanism is currently parsing the initial URL input and what exactly it is doing with it.

How do I debug (for example in Chrome) to determine who is messing with the URL and determining where each should go?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the Network tab in the chrome dev tools to see what requests are being made?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your directory structure looks like, my best suggestion would be to grep for ngRoute or angular-route.js. Those are most often the common words and phrases associated with routing files.